# how can i throw the ball with force?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a basketball in the game. If it is close to the basketball hoop, the ball automatically goes to the hoop. But if the distance is different, I want him to throw the ball at a certain height. I can throw the ball forward and up, but it's not like real throwing a ball. How can I do that? Codes I've written so far.

[image]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NBallTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Transform targetPos;
    public float T = 0;
    public bool perfectShot = false;
    public bool isFlying = false;
    public bool isFinish = false;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ComputerTesting();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            Collider coll = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>();
            coll.material.bounciness = 0.965f;
            isFlying = false;

            if (isFinish)
            {
                coll.material.bounciness = 0.3f;
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Basket"))
        {
            isFinish = true;
        }
    }

    //GetMobileInputs

    void ComputerTesting()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(targetPos.position, transform.position);

        float xMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float zMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(xMov * 3f, rb.velocity.y, zMov *3f);
        

        //Distance'a göre perfect shot olayını aktif et ve perfect shot yoksa belli bir oranda zıplatmayı yaptır.
        //perfect shot
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isFinish && !isFlying && dist >= 7)
        {
            Collider coll = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>();
            coll.material.bounciness = 0.4f;
            rb.AddForce(targetPos.position.x * 1f, targetPos.position.y * 80f, targetPos.position.z * 1500f);
            isFlying = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isFinish && !isFlying && dist < 7) //isFinish sistemini entegre et
        {
            perfectShot = true;
            isFlying = true;
            T = 0;
        }

        if (perfectShot)
        {
            //duration of air time
            T += Time.deltaTime;
            float duration = 0.5f;
            float t01 = T / duration;

            // lerping to target automatically
            Vector3 start = gameObject.transform.position;
            Vector3 end = targetPos.position;
            Vector3 position = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, t01);

            Vector3 arc = Vector3.up * 1.5f * Mathf.Sin(t01 * 3.14f);

            gameObject.transform.position = position + arc;
            isFlying = true;
            // the moment is when the ball arrive to the target point
            if (t01 > 1)
            {
                perfectShot = false;
                Collider coll = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>();
                coll.material.bounciness = 0.3f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt you just apply weight to the ball so it uses gravity? And only do it once. When you throw it not every frame as you are always applying force that way

Comment: I don't fully understand, should I increase the weight of the ball in rigidbody - mass?

Comment: The ball just needs a simple weight. Set at the inspector. If you then apply a force at time of throw. It will act like the real world.

Comment: Unless you are using _kinematics_ (which you aren't) just let Unity do all the ball-bouncing-gravity-stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- It is very strange, that you are assigning velocity to your ball every frame. I mean, `ComputerTesting()` is called every frame and in the beginning, you set a new velocity manually.
- It is also very strange that you are trying to set `gameObject.transform.position` manually. If you use physics - operate with Rigidbody, not transform.

So, remove your update for rigidbody's velocity, and remove setting `transform.position` manually. If your rigidbody is not kinematic, you should see your arc after adding force to the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I deleted the rb.velocity on my code and its working now but i need to move my object how can i do it ?

Comment: Cannot understand the problem actually. You have the gameObject with the attached rigidbody to it. It should sync position and rotation with the rigidbody parameters automatically. So in case of working with physics - use rigidbody methods to move your object (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) instead of changing `gameObject.transform` directly

Comment: gameObject.transform only happens when the ball is close to the hoop. When it goes to the automatic basketball hoop, the game is over and I don't get any input from the user after that. I find a solution with 
if (!isFlying){move codes}. Now everything is working. Thank you again. I'll try to throw it with rigidbody instead of transform though.